# make does not resolve absolute path to target name

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a simple target in my Makefile:

```
file1:
    touch $@
```

I can build this target using: `make file1`

It also builds if I say: `make ./file1` ('file1' is up to date)

However if i say: `make $HOME/file1` then it tells me:

`make: Nothing to be done for '/home/jesaremi/file1'`

Is there a way to get consistent results regardless of what path I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another rule:

```
$(shell pwd)/%: %
    @:
```

This will allow the `file1` rule to work for "file1", "./file1", "/home/jesaremi/path_to_cwd/file1", "~jesaremi/path_to_cwd/file1" and "~/path_to_cwd/file1".